# Find value in JSON returned by webservice (uri)

Tags: ansible

I call a webservice, which returns a *json* response. Here is the task:

```
- name: calls webservice for json
  uri:
    url: ...
    method: GET
    body_format: json
  register: json_response
```

Here is a simplified response returned by the called webservice:

```
{
  "nodes": {
    "hash1": {
      "name": "host1"
    },
    "hash2": {
      "name": "host2"
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, *nodes* in the returned response is a map. Each entry represents some host. Keys are some hash values, and are not important for me. I need to check if *name* in any of these documents contains a specified value, eg. "host1".

How can I check if the returned JSON contains a specified host in the *name* field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with the [json_query](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#json-query-filter) filter which uses [JMESPath](http://jmespath.org/tutorial.html) behind the scenes.

A simple playbook for your problem would look like this:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: False
  vars:
    json_query: "nodes.*[] | [?name=='host1']"
    json_response: |
      {
        "nodes": {
          "hash1": {
            "name": "host1"
          },
          "hash2": {
            "name": "host2"
          }
        }
      }

  tasks:
  - name: debug
    debug:
      msg: "{{ json_response | from_json | json_query(json_query) }}"
```